# Main class can not be found or loaded when running using command prompt

Tags: java

I would like to run my Java program using command prompt but I got an error `Main class can not be found or loaded`. Here is my Java Class:

```
package date_time;

import java.util.Date;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Date Time: " + date.toString());

    }

}
```

I put the Java file in folder: `C:\Users\sduong\workspace\DateTimeDemo\src\date_time`. And then I used `javac` to compile, then inside my folder there are two files: `Demo.class` and `Demo.java`. Then I use command: `java Demo` to run but it not work, I also tried `java date_time.Demo, java -cp Demo, java -cp date_time.Demo` but none of them worked. I set also my **Path Variable** already to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`.  Can anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: You have to create the package structure as folders in your working directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean this is the question you've made, basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to Change to Directory `C:\Users\sduong\workspace\DateTimeDemo\src\`

and run the command:

```
 java -cp .\ date_time.Demo
```